# Regex : How would I use Negative Lookahead to exclude specific character that may come in front or after the search term

Tags: regex, visual-studio

Lets say I have a C++ class CAnimal. On cpp file, I would have bunch of definition that starts with CAnimal::XXX along with CAnimal::CAnimal as constructor.

With regular expression, I would like to search the line that has CAnimal but exclude everything that is related as class method definition.

I came up with `.*CAnimal(?!::)`

However, this would display any constructor (because rear portion of constructor ::CAnimal is not followed by ::)

So I tried to use `.*CAnimal.*(?!::)`

However, this includes everything unlike I was imagining.

How can I just search for a line that has CAnimal without any method definition nor constructor?

If I had lines that contains CAnimals as below,

```
CAnimal Bob;
CAnimal Cat;
CAnimal::CAnimal()
CAnimal::MoveSpeed()
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAnimal, CWinApp)
```

I just would like to extract

```
CAnimal Bob;
CAnimal Cat;
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAnimal, CWinApp)
```

Comment: Why not use something like clangs libtooling so you can actually search the AST rather than doing primitive text searches with regular expressions?

Comment: Mainly because I have never been exposed to the concept of AST. This is very interesting way of reading code. Thank you very much! I will look into it.

Comment: @ShintaroTakechi `std::regex` does not support lookbehinds. Did you use `boost::regex`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this question was aimed toward the use of regex on Visual Studio searching functionality. I mentioned C++ because that is the specific file I was searching in, but I was not implementing the regex as a functionality of my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this pattern: `(?<!::)CAnimal(?!::)`.

It uses negative lookarounds :)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cSW4qE/1)

Comment: If look"ahead" exists, I should have expected look"behind". Thanks!